# Initiate Multiple request and handle responses by saving to DataBase in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous

I need to initiate 7 request parallely and i need to start progressbar, the response of those 7 request will be more than 1000 records as well as one flag will be present in every response to indicate whether i need to initiate the same request again to fetch the remaining data also.

Parallely i need to save those records to Database. Once every record saved i need to stop progress bar.

Can someone please let me know how to perform these operations asyncronously.

The following are the steps i need to perform Asyncronously,

Step 1: Start Progressbar for the first request alone.

Step 2: Start initiating request.

Step 3: Check flag from every response, iF 'Y' again initiate the same request and save the fetched data to DB. IF 'N' save the fetched data to DB.(DB should not lock)

Step 4: Repeat Step 3 upto every response completed with flag 'N'

Step 5: Once every response got from server and stored into Databse, need to stop Progressbar.

The Following is the selector i used to initiate the request every time,

```
-(void)requestResponseHandling
{
     [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:targetrequest
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,NSData *data, NSError *error)
     {
         [self doSomethingWithData:data];

         [[[MySingleton sharedMySingleton]progressView]removeFromSuperview];

     }];

     [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(pageLoaded:)
                       withObject:nil
                    waitUntilDone:YES];
}
```

The Following is the selector i used to check the flag and save to DB,

```
-(void)doSomethingWithData :(NSData*)data //:(NSString*)MD
{
    Webservice_Response=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSError *parseError = nil;

    xmlDictionary = [self dictionaryForXMLString:Webservice_Response error:&parseError];

    NSDictionary *table_dict=[[xmlDictionary valueForKey:@"Response"]valueForKey:@"data"];

    NSArray *table_Name=[table_dict allKeys]; //check here
    NSString *DataExistsflg;
    NSArray *tran_status;
    if([table_Name containsObject:@"table1"])
    {
        tran_status= [table_dict forKey:@"table1"];
    }
    else if([table_Name containsObject:@"table3"])
    {
        tran_status= [table_dict forKey:@"table4"];
    }
    //Similarly for all tables i ill check here

   DataExistsflg=[[[tran_status objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"DATAEXISTS"]valueForKey:@"text"];
   [self DataExists :DataExistsflg:moduleID];

   dbwrraperOBJ = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath];
   [dbwrraperOBJ open];
   [self WebserviceResponse:xmlDictionary]; //Save the server resposponse to Database
   [dbwrraperOBJ close];
}
```

I know that Progress bar will stop once every response received before saving to database. But my requirement is to stop progressbar after every step has completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of `Dispatch_Group` :)

Dispatch_Group is intended for monitoring the completion of Asynchronous independent blocks :)

So here is a pseudo code.

Declare these properties at instance level

```
let progressBar : MBProgressHUD! = nil
let group: DispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
let queue = DispatchQueue.main
```

Write a method that you will call recursively to make web service calls.

```
func makeWebServiceCall(with url : NSURL,parameters param : [String : String]) {
        if progressBar == nil {
            progressBar = create_your_progress_bar
            progressBar.show()
        }
        group.enter()
        Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: param, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: [AUTH_TOKEN_KEY : AUTH_TOKEN])
            .responseJSON { response in
                //process your json
                //update your db
                //check for your flag
                group.leave()
                if DataExistsFlag == true {
                    self.makeWebServiceCall(with: your_url, parameters: your_params)
                }
        }
        group.notify(queue: queue, execute: {() -> Void in
            progressBar.hide()
            progressBar = nil
        })
    }
```

Observe carefully where you enter and leave dispatch group. If you enter and don't leave dispatch group properly, your `group.notify` will never be called hence your progress bar will never be removed.

Comment: Thanks for your response.This helped to fix the problem